# Formula that, based on the value in column A, multiplies column B by a specific value and returns final value in column C

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am looking for a formula that will return a value in column C, by looking at column A and based on that criterion multiply the value in column B by a specific multiplier.  I am obviously doing something major wrong.  I am getting a true response, when I am looking for a calculation.

What I am looking for:

If A = Apple, multiple B by 40 and return the value in C,
If A = Banana, multiple B by 40 and return the value in C,
If A = Kiwi, multiply B by 20 and return the value in C,
If A = Orange, multiply B by 30 and return the value in C.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming row 1 has headers and your data start in row 2, enter this formula into cell C2:

```
=B2*CHOOSE(MATCH(A2,{"Apple";"Banana";"Kiwi";"Orange"},),40,40,20,30)
```

Now copy it down as far as you like.

Comment: That's pretty neat, I like `Choose()`, I'll have to remember that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your fruit type is in column A, with your numbers in Column B, in C1, 
`=IF(A1="Apple",B1*40,IF(A1="Banana",B1*40,IF(A1="Kiwi",B1*20,IF(A1="Orange",B1*30))))`

Another option is to create a table that has your fruit name in one column, and the multiplier next to it:

```
Fruit   Multiplier
Apple   40
Banana  40
Kiwi    20
Orange  30
```

and you can use a `Vlookup()` formula instead. Assume the table above is range F1:G5.  Place this formula in C1: `=B1*VLOOKUP(A1,$F$2:$G$5,2,FALSE)`